# Gulp not updating output css with new scss file

Tags: css, gulp

So I've been working on this project for a little while and I wanted to add my own css into the project. I'm trying to add a new scss file to the project and have it get built into the main css file, however Gulp doesn't want to import my scss file.

Here is the gulp code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var batch = require('gulp-batch');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

var paths = {
  sass: ['src/scss/**'],
  js: ['src/ng/_declare.js', 'src/ng/**'], //_declare.js needs to be first, so it gets added to bundle first.
  static: ['src/js/**'],
  core: ['./td_frontend_shared/**']
};

gulp.task('default', ['watch-dev']);

gulp.task('publish-dev', function(done){

});

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('src/scss/import.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.log('error building sass', err);
      done();
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist/'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the task in default if you want it run right away on using `gulp` in command line. You can do it like this...

```
gulp.task( 'default', function () {
    gulp.start(
        'sass'
    );
} );
```

Try my repository for using SASS in HTML projects, it supports babel(optional) and auto reloads page when you change `scss` files ;)

https://github.com/shramee/gulp-sass-babel

Comment: it is easy enough to just run `gulp sass`, and also I'm trying to figure out why my new scss file isn't being added to the css file being built. (I use that as its own function to call it in multiple tasks, (sorry didn't include the whole gulp file, but wanted to keep this short

Comment: What is your directory structure? Which file you are trying to edit? Which file do you expect CSS to be added to?

Comment: after spending some time I found that there was a scss file that was used to import all of the new scss files, I didn't know that my gulp file imports the scss files from the import.scss file

Comment: Okay... Great :)